# How to upgrade pip3.6

Tags: python, linux

I use Linux, Debian for Python 3.6.4, I also use pip3.6. It has asked me a lot to upgrade but it will not work, I always get this error.

Already, I have tried pip3.6 install ---upgrade pip

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LXVni.png]

Comment: Please provide us with the line of bash that you ran, and the error code, in text here so that we don't need to read a screenshot. Thanks!

Comment: I suggest to uninstall, then do an update, then finally install pip3.6 again

Comment: I honestly don't know how to, keeps on saying code not formatted

Comment: Looks like you need to `sudo pip3.6 install --upgrade pip` for this to work on your machine if you have permissions to do that.

Comment: `sudo python -m pip install -U pip`. Assuming you have Python 3 as default. If not substitute `python` by your proper command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try `sudo pip3.6 install --upgrade pip`. If that does not work, reinstall pip.